# How to add users in the Freestyle Support portal in joomla

Tags: joomla

I added users in the freestyle under one group , but the name is not displaying in the front end.[image]

Already under freestyle settings i added the name under branches admin, but it is not showing

Comment: Freestyle Support Portal seems to have been discontinued so it's going to be difficult for anyone to help with this unless they already have a copy of the software or you share a relevant code snippet here.

Comment: You might also consider asking this question on the dedicated SE site [joomla.se]

Comment: Thanks fo rthe coperation, if the person is super admin no body can assign him any ticket, if the person is not super admin. everybody can assign.